# Deriving the vector field from a curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, curl

If $B= (x/r^3,y/r^3,z/r^3)$ find a vector $A$ such that $curl A = B$.
 My attempt:

$∂A_3∂Y−∂A_2∂Z=x/r^3$

$∂A_1∂Z−∂A_2∂y=y/r^3$

$∂A_2∂x−∂A_1∂y=z/r^3$

I assumed $A_3=0$, ending up having to solve:

$A_2=\int xr^{-3}dz$

Here, I got stuck. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: The problem is way more interesting since $\;r=\left\|(x,y,z)\right\|\implies r^3=\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}\;$ , isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I assume your book asks for *any* solution even though physically meaningless. Take for instance $A_3 = 0$. Then

\begin{equation}
B_1 = \frac{\partial A_3}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial A_2}{\partial z} = \frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
A_2 = -\int \frac{x}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3} \mathrm{d}z = \frac{-xz}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\end{equation}
Similarly,
\begin{equation}
B_2 = \frac{\partial A_1}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_3}{\partial x} = \frac{y}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
A_1 = \int \frac{y}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3} \mathrm{d}z = \frac{yz}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\end{equation}

---

Solving $\nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$ is a coupled partial differential equation, which is not complete unless boundary conditions are given to make solution $\mathbf{A}$ unique. Otherwise, the following answer assumes $\mathbf{A}$ is zero on boundary (decays at infinity).

By [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), every vector field $\mathbf{B}$ is decomposed to a curl-free and divergence-free component, by
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A} - \nabla \phi,
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is the potential (the *curl-free* part, since $\nabla \times (\nabla \phi) = 0$), and $\mathbf{A}$ is vector potential (the *divergence-free* part, since $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) = 0$). Here

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{0} - \nabla \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \right) = -\nabla \left(\frac{1}{r}\right).
\end{equation}

It means $\mathbf{B}$ can be decomposed into a potential field $\phi=r^{-1}$ and no vector potential $\mathbf{A}$.

The potential is unique upto a constant, $\phi = \frac{1}{r}+c$ for any constant $c$. The vector potential is unique up to a gradient field, $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0} + \nabla \psi$ for any scalar field $\psi$.

Indeed, $\mathbf{B} = \frac{1}{r^2}\mathbf{e}_r$ is the Coulomb force, which is curl free and represented by potential above.

---

Comment: The book from which the question is taken claims that $A=(yz/r(x^2+y^2), -xz/r(x^2+y^2), 0)$.

Comment: Both answers are correct. They differ because they have different _boundary conditions_. For the answer in the book, the solution does not decay at infinity (for instance, take limit when $z \to \infty$ for some non-zero $x$ and $y$). In general, when you solve a differential equation, a boundary condition should be provided, otherwise it is assumed the solution is zero at boundary (here it meas the solution decays at infinity). I will note these in my answer to clarify confusion.

Comment: It's not true that there is no vector potential that tends to zero at infinity, the decomposition theorem does not claim that.

Comment: You are right, but I did not infer it from the decomposition. No BC was given, so we assume solutions have compact support. Then the solution with a given BC is unique up to Gauge conditions for Helmholtz decomposition.

Comment: My claim is this: there is an $\mathbf A$ s.t. $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$ and $\mathbf A$ vanishes when $r \to \infty$.

Comment: I appreciate the discussion Maxim. For a specific boundary condition, any $\mathbf{A}$ in the form of $\mathbf{A}' = \mathbf{A}+\nabla \psi$ is also a solution of above decomposition, so as any $\phi'=\phi +c$. A Gauge condition fixes them to a unique solution. If we impose $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$ (there are good reasons for such in physics), then the only $\mathbf{A}$ with compact support would be $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0}$. You can make other solutions with compact support (decay) that are not zero.

Comment: Your answer says that any $\mathbf A$ which tends to zero at infinity has the form $\nabla \psi$, therefore $\nabla \times \mathbf A = 0$ and we cannot have $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$. This is the statement which is incorrect.

Comment: In general, $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A} + \nabla \phi$. Assume we are interested in solutions that decay. Then $\mathbf{A} = \nabla \psi$ and $\phi = \frac{1}{r}+c$. Thus, if one wishes to solve $\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$, the answer is: $\mathbf{A}$ dost exists with such boundary condition since $\mathbf{B}$ is only made of scalar potential. This is what I originally posted, before the OP hint me the boundary condition is not important in this question. However, I kept the extra discussion at the end of the solution. The statements in the extra discussion is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was thinking about $\mathbf A$ which solves $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$ in a simply connected domain such as a sector between two rays from the origin. But we cannot extend this $\mathbf A$ smoothly to $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$, you're right.

Comment: Your counter example was indeed right, it was just not in $L^2_{\operatorname{div}}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ space, that is required by the decomposition. There are some technicalities that I have avoid since they diverge from the topic of this thread.

Comment: In fact, I do have a different objection, namely, that the behavior at infinity is irrelevant. The answer is just this: a solution of $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf B$ may exist in some region but not in $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$, regardless of the boundary conditions imposed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to construct a solution of $\nabla \times \mathbf A = \mathbf r/r^3$ that would be valid in $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \{(0, 0, 0)\}$. Otherwise, taking $\mathcal S$ to be a sphere centered at the origin, we would get
$$\int_{\mathcal S} \mathbf B \cdot d\mathbf S = 4 \pi =
\int_{\partial \mathcal S} \mathbf A \cdot d\mathbf s = 0.$$
If we want a solution in a region not containing a closed surface around the origin, we can take $\mathbf A = A_\theta \mathbf e_\theta$:
$$\nabla \times (A_\theta \mathbf e_\theta) =
-\frac 1 {r \sin \theta} \frac {\partial A_\theta } {\partial \phi} \mathbf e_r +
\frac 1 r \frac {\partial (r A_\theta)} {\partial r} \mathbf e_\phi.$$
The second term disappears if $A_\theta = f(\theta, \phi)/r$. Then we can set $f(\theta, \phi) = -\phi \sin \theta$.