# Show that the inverse square field has a vector potential for all points except along the $x_3$ axis.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Show that the inverse square field
\begin{align*}
\frac{-X}{\| x\|^3}=-\frac{(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align*}
has a vector potential
\begin{align*}
\frac{x_3}{\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{\left(-x_2, x_1, 0 \right)}{x_1^2+x_2^2}
\end{align*}
For all points except along the $x_3$ axis.

A vector field $F$ has a vector potential $G$ when it can be expressed as $F=curl\:G$. So, I have to show:

\begin{align*}
curl\left(\frac{x_3}{\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{\left(-x_2, x_1, 0 \right)}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)=-\frac{(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align*}

???

Comment: If the curl of the vector field is zero, you have a conservative vector field and the vector field can be written as gradient of a potential function.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3332324

Comment: @MathLover that's a very false statement in general (also, doesn't seem directly relevant in this case, because OP is asking about a vector potential). The solution in this case is simply a direct calculation.

Comment: @peek-a-boo there is nothing false about my statement. But yes I should have paid more attention as I misread the question and that it was asking about a vector potential.

Comment: @MathLover vanishing curl does not imply it can be written as a gradient of a scalar everywhere; this is only true locally (Poincare's lemma). That's why I said it's false in general (similarly, this field does not admit a vector potential on $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, only on $\Bbb{R}^3$ minus an axis).

Comment: @peek-a-boo while you are correct that my statement is not true  _everywhere_, I am a bit confused. Yes we all know Poincare's lemma but why are you expecting an _answer_ in a comment? If I see a student is trying to find potential function, I would leave a comment asking them to first check whether the curl is zero. But if you have more time, please go ahead and explain to OP in more detail. In any case thanks for pointing out that I completely misread the question.

Comment: @MathLover I left that comment to warn OP not to take the statement exactly as written too literally, because many students (myself included a few years ago) have the misconception that vanishing curl (resp divergence) implies a global existence of scalar (resp. vector) potential. But yea I should have also addressed the OP directly (and I didn't write an answer because this is literally a direct calculation question and OP hasn't yet shown any computations).

Comment: To OP: where exactly are you stuck? The question tells you exactly what to do. You're supposed to calculate the curl of the LHS using the definition of curl, and show that (after some slightly tedious algebra) you end up with the RHS. If you elaborate on what you have done so far, and where exactly you're stuck/what is unclear then I'd be happy to elaborate more, but as of right now you're essentially asking us to give you a full detailed calculation without showing anything.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Then it is to do this:

Comment: \begin{align*}
\nabla \left(-\frac{(x_1, x_2, x_3)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \right)= 
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \\
\frac{-x_1}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & \frac{-x_2}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} & \frac{-x_3}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: No, look at the last equation of your post. Calculate the LHS using the definition. What do you get/where are you stuck?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Well, then I have the following:

Comment: \begin{align*}
\nabla \left( \frac{x_3}{\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{\left(-x_2, x_1, 0 \right)}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \right)=\nabla \left( \frac{-x_3x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}},\frac{x_3x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}},0 \right)
\end{align*}=

Comment: \begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
i & j & k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} & \frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} \\
\frac{-x_3x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} & \frac{x_3x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} & 0
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: ok, now expand out that whole determinant and simplify

Comment: @peek-a-boo \begin{align*}
\left( -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\left(\frac{x_3x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \right),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\left(\frac{-x_3x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \right),\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\left(\frac{x_3x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\left(\frac{-x_3x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2\left( x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \right) \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Ok now continue calculating those partial derivatives

Comment: @peek-a-boo \begin{align*}
\left( -\frac{x\left(x_1^2\left(x_3^2+x_1^2+x_2^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+x_1^2x_2^2+x_2^4\right)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\left(x_3^2+x_1^2+x_2^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}, -\frac{x_2\left(x_1^2\left(x_3^2+x_2^2+x_1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}+x_2^2x_1^2+x_2^4\right)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\left(x_3^2+x_2^2+x_1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} , \ldots \right) 
\end{align*}

Comment: \begin{align*}
\ldots \frac{x_3\left(x_2^4+x_3^2x_2^2-x_1^2\left(x_3^2+x_1^2+x_2^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\left(x_3^2+x_1^2+x_2^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{x_3\left(-2x_2^4-x_3^2x_2^2-x_2^2x_1^2+x_1^2\left(x_3^2+x_2^2+x_1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\left(x_2^2+x_3^2+x_1^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{align*}